Initializing SolrCores in ddev for TYPO3 v12 fails
I am trying to integrate solr in my TYPO3 v12 ddev setup, but getting this error:

core_en: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.apache.solr.response.XSLTResponseWriter'

In the projects root directory I executed the following commands:

mkdir -p .ddev/solr
cp -r vendor/apache-solr-for-typo3/solr/Resources/Private/Solr/* .ddev/solr

And this is my docker-compose.solr.yaml file:
services:
  solr:
    container_name: ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-solr
    image: typo3solr/ext-solr:12.0.5
    restart: "no"
    expose:
      - 8983
    labels:
      com.ddev.site-name: ${DDEV_SITENAME}
      com.ddev.approot: $DDEV_APPROOT
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=$DDEV_HOSTNAME
      - HTTP_EXPOSE=8983
    volumes:
      - "./solr:/opt/solr/server/solr"
      # If you want your solr to persist over `ddev stop` and `ddev start` then uncomment the following line
      # If you uncomment it and want to flush your data you have to `ddev stop` and then
      # `docker volume rm ddev-<projectname>_solrdata` to destroy it.
      - solr:/var/solr
  web:
    links:
      - solr

volumes:
  # solr is a persistent Docker volume for this project's solr data
  # the volume will be named ddev-<project>_solr
  solr:

Now calling http://myproject.ddev.site:8983/solr/#/ in the browser throws the error described above.
What needs to be changed, that the solr cores can be initialized?

I would try to make it work with https://github.com/ddev/ddev-typo3-solr or https://github.com/ddev/ddev-solr, and then look into integrating the typo3solr/ext-solr image, if necessary.

You don't want the volume - "./solr:/opt/solr/server/solr", most probably there is the trouble. By-side of that Apache Solr service wants proper UNIX UID+GID file permissions inside of image.
So stop your project and remove the files from volumes, then remove the mentioned line from docker-compose.solr.yaml and start again.
If you run on ARM and not on x86, then you want to build the image manually.
See:

https://github.com/TYPO3-Solr/ext-solr/issues/2891
https://github.com/TYPO3-Solr/solr-ddev-site/blob/release-12.0.x/.ddev/docker-compose.solr.yaml

